# Reclaim lost space on disk (reverting back From bootcamp)

Tags: macos, terminal, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

​Long story short, I was attempting to get rid of Bootcamp and somehow botched it so I can't get into either Windows or macOS anymore. I fiddled with some partition stuff and I think I made things worse.

I'm just looking to get macOS reinstalled on my ~2016 iMac to be able to use it again.

(I don't care about any data on the disk)

I have a 2 TB hard drive, but in Disk Utility, it's only showing around 520GB. I'd like to get the full hard drive space back before reinstalling macOS.

Below is info from `diskUtil List` and `diskUtil CS list`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Attempting to do it the way that you're showing (by using the Partition button within Disk Utility) is probably the easiest and most supported method. Can you expand the list of disks to show "Show All Devices" by going to the View menu > Show All Devices, and then post an updated screenshot of what you see when attempting to Partition the physical Fusion Drive set when it's divulged?

Comment: @EddieKelley: I suspect the Disk Utility application shown in the OP's question does not have a View menu > Show All Devices. I also suspect the images in the OP's question are already showing all devices. In other words, the OP is using version of macOS (OS X) Recovery at least older than High Sierra.

Comment: @DavidAnderson is correct, I do not have a View button to select anywhere. The iMac is on version  10.11.2 Build 15C50.

Comment: Randy: Your comment answered a couple of questions. First, you are using El Capitan. Second, since Apple did not make an iMac in 2016 and a 2017 iMac can not run El Capitan, I assume you have a 2015 iMac. Do you want to reinstall El Capitan or some other newer version of macOS? Are you booting to the OS X Recover from your internal drives or from Internet Recovery? If booting from Internet Recovery, is the version of OS X (macOS) the same as you want to install? (You can get the version by entering the command `sw_vers`.)

Comment: Installing the latest OSX version would be ideal. I am booting from OS X Recover. I booted into internet recovery mode and the version is 10.11.6 build 15g31. I assume I can upgrade once booted into any version. The main part is getting the full 2TB hard drive back and usable.

Comment: From the output you posted, I suppose the command to get the full 2TB hard drive back and usable would be `diskutil cs resizestack disk3 0`. Here, I assume the core storage structure has not been damaged and the `Macintosh HD` volume is still `disk3`.

Comment: So where does this leave your question? Have you found a way to boot OS X or macOS?

Comment: Yes, I got OSX reinstalled and upgraded to Monterey, all with full 2tb of hard drive space. If you make your comment an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I posted an answer. Did you reinstall El Capitan, then upgrade directly to Monterey? Or, did you go a different route? If you reinstalled El Capitan, did you use OS X Recover from the internal drives or Internet Recovery? I am interesting in knowing in case another user asks a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output you posted, I the command to get the full 2 TB hard drive back and usable is given below.

```
diskutil cs resizestack disk3 0
```

Here, I assume the core storage structure has not been damaged and the `Macintosh HD` volume is still `disk3`.

You can also choose to substitute the logical volume UUID for `disk3`, which in this case would be `9D544FC6-4616-4F69-ABF1-6744F6810F9A`.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: If you truly don't care about anything on the disk, the simplest way to do this is to boot into Internet Recovery (Shift-Option-Command-R), which will allow you to completely re-partition the drive (since you're not booted off the on-disk recovery partition).

You can then fully repartition the disk with `diskutil eraseDisk` and the like, or with Disk Utility (just make sure you have **View -> Show All Devices** enabled).

Option 2: If you are not running Big Sur, you should still have the option `diskutil cs`**`revert`**, `diskutil cs`**`delete`**, and `diskutil cs`**`deleteVolume`**. See the "Delete Core Storage Volume" section [of this article here](https://www.lifewire.com/split-fusion-drive-apart-2260166).

Comment: Appreciate the help, though I figured it out using David's commands!